# Oracle streams how exclude chages in sequences in schema replication

Tags: oracle, replication, sequence, oracle-streams

I have two DBs I want to synchronize using streams

So I followed N-way replication guide.
I have following config:

```
   BEGIN
      DBMS_STREAMS_ADM.ADD_SCHEMA_RULES(
        schema_name    => 'schema_A',
        streams_type   => 'capture',
        streams_name   => 'capture_A',
        queue_name     => 'strmadmin.captured_DBA',
        include_dml    => TRUE,
        include_ddl    => TRUE,
        inclusion_rule => TRUE);
    END;
    /
    BEGIN
      DBMS_STREAMS_ADM.ADD_SCHEMA_RULES(
        schema_name     => 'schema_A',
        streams_type    => 'apply',
        streams_name    => 'apply_from_DBB',
        queue_name      => 'strmadmin.from_DBB',
        include_dml     => TRUE,
        include_ddl     => TRUE,
        source_database => 'DB_B',
        inclusion_rule  => TRUE);
    END;
```

I also want to utilize the sequence hint so I don't have duplicate keys:

```
create sequence SEQ1 ... start with 1 increment by 2...; --on DB A
create sequence SEQ1 ... start with 2 increment by 2...; --on DB B
```

Bu since I have schema replication if I run those two create sequence commands I have SEQ1 start with 2 increment by 2 on both DBs

Is it possible to exclude changes on sequences in schema replication or I need to change to table replication and specify all tables one by one?

Comment: What NWay replication guide did you followed?